# Banei Abir clan of Habbani Yemenite Jewry

Tags: history, tefilin, yemenite-temani

There's this video for "ancient tefillin wrapping" that shows a wrapping style utilizing the paleo-hebrew characters. The statement is that this method of wrapping is preserved by the "Banei Abir clan of Habbani Yemenite Jewry" but i'm not able to find more information about them. Does anyone know more, or have more pictures of this clan of Jews wearing tefillin?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5JqkbCputI

Comment: I can't tell, is the shin in the tefillin shel rosh ashuri?

Comment: It should be. The halacha is that the writing and everything else should be ashuri. But how you wind/wrap the tefillin is minhag, so technically you could do it almost anyway you wanted. (Although i think there might be a halacha that one needs at least 7 wrappings)

Comment: @Aaron non habbani teimonimtie the same way except they wrap the last wraps on the middle of the hand and not around the wrist. safaradim other mizrahim tie the same way except the make the line with the strap around their thumb instead of making a paleo hebrew dol(triangle). they dont make the sheen and i dont think other teimonim make the sheen as well now a days but they mightve before i didnt do research on how they made the sheen on the hand that much. just that i know both mizrahim/safaradim and teimonim tie the same and both are paleo hebrew in a sense

Comment: its worthy mentioning that if people wore the tafillin all day the palm should be free so wrapping the last straps around the wrist makes more sense than the middle of the hand

Comment: @Aaron - While there are certainly Jews from Habaan in Yemen who do have some peculiar customs from their region of origin, nobody exactly wraps this way. The problem is that the guy in the video, the "Abir clan" of "Habbani warriors," and making paleo-Hebrew letters with your straps are all phoney. I am telling you from personal experience with these matters. Real Habaanim look much like their Baladi and Shaami counterparts. Here is a video of real Habaanim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECxODKOo_P8

Comment: @Aaron - The fact is that there is no "secret mesora" of any clan on how to wrap the straps of the t'philin. Rather, they had family traditions like Jews from other parts of the world did. I have seen a great many variations by Yemenites, both similar and dissimilar to what is shown in the video you posted. The truth is that they did not give too much thought to these things unless they were inclined to follow the Qabbala. Everyone else just made sure they fulfilled the conditions of the Rambam in the MT. And the Rambam himself in a t'shuva says that it can be wrapped around the wrist. Kol tuv

Comment: ...I know personally that that guy is sincere, but his "beth midrash" does not exist, neither does his "community," and the rest is just hype. It's like those people who get sucked into every conspiracy theory and health trend that there is and swear by it. My advice is to stick with authentic Yemenites and those who authentically bear the tradition, like Rav Rasson Arusi, Rav Elyaqim Ssadoq, Rav Mahfudh, et al. Hope this helps. Kol Tuv.

Comment: It does indeed help. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes i know a habani the man who taught the guy in the video send your message to 'contact us' of this website http://www.abirwarriorarts.com/en to get hold of the aluph abir

Comment: @Aaron There is no halacha of 7 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13340/759